# Python Jinja2 ordered list

Tags: python, jinja2

EDIT :
I have a python list like this obtained by requesting a mongodb database :

```py
db.coll.find()
> ["Create", "Infra", "Consolidate"]
```

Is there a way to say in jinja2 template to sort the list in a defined order ? I want an order like this :

```py
["Infra", "Create", "Consolidate"]
```

I would be happy if something like the following worked. Unfortunately, this is not the case :

```py
{% for item in list|sort("Infra", "Create", "Consolidate") %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What's the reasoning for this order?

Comment: A customer-defined constraint :/ It's a process. the first step is the "Infra", then go to the "Create" section et so on.

Comment: Then just... pass this specific list. `{% for item in ["Infra", "Create", "Consolidate"] %}`

Comment: Note that you pass a tuple to the sort function, not a list. Tuples are immutable.

Comment: I notice there is a lack of informations. The orignal list ["Create", "Infra", "Consolidate"] is obtained by requesting a mongodb database : db.coll.find(). I just editing the original message.

Comment: I found my answer with custom sort based on this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75643901/11758711